# How to add process variable in process definition on task assignment?

Tags: activiti

I am trying to add a process variable when a task is assigned by adding following inside userTask block:

```
<activiti:taskListener event="assignment" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener">
        <activiti:field name="script">
          <activiti:string><![CDATA[
              execution.setVariable("taskAssignedTo", task.assignee);
            ]]>
          </activiti:string>
        </activiti:field>
        <activiti:field name="language">
          <activiti:string><![CDATA[JavaScript]]></activiti:string>
        </activiti:field>
</activiti:taskListener>
```

But it throws error as:

> org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Exception while invoking TaskListener: Exception while invoking TaskListener: problem evaluating script: ReferenceError: "execution" is not defined in  at line number 1
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ListenerNotificationHelper.executeTaskListeners(ListenerNotificationHelper.java:124)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ListenerNotificationHelper.executeTaskListeners(ListenerNotificationHelper.java:104)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntityManagerImpl.fireAssignmentEvents(TaskEntityManagerImpl.java:141)

What can be the cause here?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

It should be:

```
task.getExecution().setVariable("taskAssignedTo", task.assignee);
```